# installation of package ‘ggplot2’ had non-zero exit status

Tags: r, ggplot2, package, rlang

I am trying to install ggplot2, which I had previously had installed however, I keep on getting an error message saying

> ggplot2 had non-zero exit status.

I have updated R, unistalled and reinstalled it.
I have also done `"install.packaged("ggplot2", dependencies = TRUE)`, that did not work, I have tried to install each dependency independently, which did not work.
 I have tried to update some of the dependencies, especially rlang, however, the version nevers changes, so again had no success... 
This is the error message

```
>install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies = TRUE)
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Liah Brown/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependency ‘rlang’


  There are binary versions available but the source versions are
  later:
        binary source needs_compilation
rlang    0.2.0  0.3.1              TRUE
ggplot2  2.2.1  3.1.0             FALSE

  Binaries will be installed
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/rlang_0.2.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 754726 bytes (737 KB)
downloaded 737 KB

package ‘rlang’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\Liah Brown\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpao258F\downloaded_packages
installing the source package ‘ggplot2’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/ggplot2_3.1.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2863109 bytes (2.7 MB)
downloaded 2.7 MB

* installing *source* package 'ggplot2' ...
** package 'ggplot2' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace 'rlang' 0.2.0 is being loaded, but >= 0.2.1 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'ggplot2'
* removing 'C:/Users/Liah Brown/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/ggplot2'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.2/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Liah Brown\Documents\R\win-library\3.3" C:\Users\LIAHBR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpao258F/downloaded_packages/ggplot2_3.1.0.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ggplot2’ had non-zero exit status
```

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\Liah Brown\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpao258F\downloaded_packages’

My session info is...

```
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] plyr_1.8.4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.3.2  yaml_2.1.18  Rcpp_0.12.16
```

And this is my .libPaths()

```
[1] "C:/Users/Liah Brown/Documents/R/win-library/3.3"
[2] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.2/library"
```

Comment: The *first* error is "`namespace 'rlang' 0.2.0 is being loaded by >= 0.2.1 is required`". So try explicitly `install.packages("rlang")`, and if you still get the error make sure you don't have an old `rlang` version lying around in any of your libraries. Use `.libPaths()` to see all the libraries (folders where packages go) that R knows about.

Comment: Check your output. The *rlang* version is too low, they should 0.2.1 but is 0.2.0. It looks like a mistake in the package. Try to install *rlang* in version 0.2.1 manually.

Comment: Also, please edit your question to include the error message as text within the question, NOT as a screenshot. Screenshots are not searchable or copy/pasteable, which makes it harder for people who might know how to help you to find and/or solve your problem.

Comment: @Gregor I have done all of that, I deleted the file in the library,  uninstalled rlang and then reinstalled it but it is still installing the 0.2.0 version.

Comment: @MirkoEbert how do I install it manually? Sorry, I am new to R

Comment: `install.packages("rlang", type = "source")`

Comment: Also, perhaps update R to the current version? You say *"I have updated R, unistalled and reinstalled it"*, but your path is showing `C:/Users/Liah Brown/Documents/R/win-library/3.3`, meaning (at least your library) is for R version 3.3. R 3.4 was released in April, 2017 and the current version is 3.6. Maybe post your `sessionInfo()` and your `.libPaths()`? It's possible you have a newer version of R installed, but you are still running an old version...

Comment: @Gregor I will post my session info + .libpaths() now

Comment: @Gregor I have posted them both now :) Thanks so much for your help

Comment: Okay, so from your session info your R version is about 2.5 years old. (`R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)` is the first line). Go in the windows "uninstall programs" interface and get rid of any old R versions and make sure the current version, 3.6.0, is installed.

Comment: @Gregor Thank you so much!

Comment: @Gregor: Can you add the link to R 3.6.0? I could only find R 3.5.2 :/

Comment: Oh, I guess 3.6.0 is the development version, not released yet. 3.5.2 is good.